# Редактирование вопросов и ответов

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

> Интересует мнение сообщества, на сколько **правильно** или **не правильно** менять название вопроса под суть обращения, а не оставлять вопрос в том виде, как его задал пользователь, если в самом вопросе нет указания на текст ошибки.

Для примера: Был задан вопрос **"Не могу добавить элемент в массив в React"**, однако исследование вопроса и причины обращения показали, что проблема не в том, что элемент не добавляется *(Он прекрасно добавлялся)* , а в том, что это приводило к ошибке **"Too many re-renders"**.

Изначально мною был дан ответ, как это исправить, затем отдельно дал второй ответ, почему такое происходит.

Через некоторое время, поняв и осмыслив цели stackOverFlow(ну во всяком случае я так считаю, что я понял суть stackOverFlow), я модифицировал ответы, расписал все(может что то и упустил) возможные причины ошибки, как их избежать и т.д. и т.п.

Далее осознав, что тема вопроса не отражает самой проблемы, я предложил правку вопроса, где, добавил в вопрос саму ошибку -> [Почему возникает ошибка в компоненте React - Too many re-renders?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders).

Вот хотел узнать мнение сообщества, на сколько это правильно, давать максимально развернутые комментарии о причине ошибки, а так же менять сам вопрос(заголовок, сам текст - минимально конечно), что бы он точно отражал саму ошибку, а не то, как это видится обратившемуся?

И на сколько приветствуются такие детализированный ответы? Стоит ли периодически проверять свои ответы и вносить в них дополнения или изменения?

Comment: хороший и полезный вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Про указанный вопрос

Видел данный вопрос.
И даже видел предложение в очереди "Предлагаемые правки"
*Правда я его пропустил и не стал голосовать ни за, ни против т.к. не было сил разбираться в том, вандализм это или же нет 

(как вы и сами заметили заголовки до и после имели мало общего)*

Тем не менее данную правку проверило несколько более опытных участников и все единогласно решили, что данная правка более чем уместна.
Значит Вы все сделали правильно и значит заголовок после вашей правки стал лучше отражать суть вопроса.

---

#### В общем

Это все частности... а если в общем то **любая правка улучшающая вопрос имеет право на существование**.

- Вы не можете править код, предоставленный автором вопроса
  *(Речь про добавление новых и изменение имеющихся конструкций в коде автора. Форматирование кода наоборот приветствуется. За исключением языков, в которых форматирование влияет на ход выполнения программы)*
- Вы не можете исправлять условия задачи
- Вы не можете искажать намерения автора

Но если автор:

- неверно толкует увиденное
- неверно предполагает ошибку
- или вовсе не считает нужным упоминуть о проблемах и ошибках в заголовке

То вполне допускается правка вопроса(в том числе и заголовка ).
*(Опять же, если то, на что вы замените заголовок не будет идти в разрез с намерениями автора, не будет являться попыткой ответа и не будет противоречить другим правилам сообщества)*

Если правка поможет

- отразить суть проблемы
- другим пользователям найти решение

**то смело вносите ее!**

В крайнем случае придут более опытные товарищи и откатят или пожурят , если вы сделали что-то не то.`¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Вы находитесь в сообществе, в котором любой может допустить ошибку. И если оступитесь Вы, то если это увидят - это постараются исправить.

По-хорошему для того, чтобы помочь понять что можно править, а что и как править ввели Gap в 2000 репутации, чтобы неопытные пользователи сначала правили вопросы и ответы под наблюдением более опытных участников. И получая обратную связь из очередей проверок Вы бы сформировали понимание того, что стоит делать, а что нет.

К сожалению, данное решение не учитывает того, что пользователь может начать исправлять вопросы ближе к достижению данного рубежа и тем самым пропустит этап "*обучения с учителем*"

---

#### Что должен содержать заголовок

stackoverflow - это база знаний и заголовок поста должен как можно лучше отражать суть проблемы или задачи автора.

- Если заголовок избыточен и содержит лишнюю информацию - ее стоит перенести непосредственно в тело вопроса.
- Если вопрос описывает ошибку или проблему, с которой столкнулся пользователь, а заголовок содержит контекст возникновения этой ошибки, то следует заголовок дополнить ошибкой, а описание контекста свести к минимуму
- Если заголовок общий и по нему невозможно предугадать, что тебя ждет в тексте, то его следует исправлять.

---

#### Права автора вопроса

Вопросы сразу после публикации становятся достоянием сообщества и теоритически, если автор начнет вносить правки ухудшающие вопрос - его правки  сначала откатят, а при многократном нарушении могут и вовсе заблокировать.
И подобные кейсы случаются. И случаются чаще, чем вы бы могли это представить.

Comment: «если автор неверно толкует увиденное» — по-моему спорно, ведь исправление этого может случайно оказаться внесением ответа в текст вопроса

Comment: @andreymal,  в подсказках и справке в очередях предлагаемых правок это указано и мне казалось что в подсказках начинающим редакторам это также должно выводиться(заводить отдельный аккаунт для проверки смысла не вижу). Но могу дополнить ответ для точности.

Comment: @andreymal - дополнил и вставил пункт рядом с исключением, говорящем о том, что правка не должна противоречить намерениям автора

Comment: *Вы не можете править код, предоставленный автором вопроса* - а что тогда Вы предлагаете делать, если в опубликованной форме код просто нечитаем? Добавлять в вопрос с соответствующей пометкой тот же код, но отформатированный? Публиковать ответ с отформатированным кодом? Игнорировать?

Comment: @Akina, речь идет про внесение изменений (добавление, изменение конструкций) в код. Форматировать код я никому не запрещал. ( За исключением python и пр. языков, в которых от  форматирования зависит ход выполнения программы )

Comment: @Akina Вопрос касался отражения смысла  и сути ошибки и правок, влияющих на ее восприятие. Поэтому и ответ был сконцентрирован на этом, а не на форматировании.

Comment: на всякий случай добавил пояснение данного пункта в ответ

Comment: *Вопросы сразу после публикации становятся достоянием сообщества* Это не совсем верно. За автором остаётся право удаления вопроса. Как по мне - право совершенно лишнее. Ибо не раз уже сталкивался с ситуацией, когда вроде даже неплохой и где-то полезный вопрос, даже имеющий принятый ответ, удаляется автором - ну типа я ответ получил, мне больше от этого вопроса ничего не надо... По большому счёту - вредное право.

Comment: @Akina, с вышеупомянутым пунктом не согласен. `Лицензиар не может отозвать эти свободы, пока вы соблюдаете условия лицензии.` В тексте лицензии указано, что автор не вправе мне запретить распространять его вопрос, пока я соблюдаю условия лицензии. Возможность удаления - это уже заморочки SO. И тут, возможно, вопрос в том, что в разное время SO исползовал разные лицензии и в ранних версиях это допускалось.

Comment: @Akina, плюс я видел множество примеров самолично удаленных аккаунтов, но при этом вопросы и ответы их остались. Возможно дело реально в версиях используемой на момент публикации вопроса или ответа.

Comment: в любом случае мне это кажестся темой для отдельного обсуждения

Comment: @Akina вот `Ваши вопросы и ответы останутся на сайте, но будут диссоциированы и анонимизированы (автор будет отображён как "user189027") и не будут отражать ваше авторство, даже если вы позднее вернётесь на сайт.` это про удаление аккаунта

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sYdwCK1.png

Comment: Я не говорю об удалении аккаунта автором вопроса - с этим моментом всё ясно и очевидно. Я говорю об удалении самого вопроса. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMCHF.png Как по мне, так удаление вопроса должно тоже коллегиально аппрувиться.

Comment: @Akina, это уже хитросплетения процессов SO. Сама лицензия явно дает понять, что мы можем распоряжаться данным контентом так как нам заблаграссудиться. Просто разработчикам SO проще зачистить аккаунт от персональной информации, чем диссоциировать вопросы по одиночке. Это не вопрос прав участников на удаление контента. Это просто нежелание разработчиков заморачиваться над этим.

Comment: @Akina, я вас понимаю и полностью разделяю ваше негодование. Я говорю о том, что в приведенном вами кейсе проблема не в лицензии и не в правах участника...а в разработчиках.

Comment: Ааа... ну это да.

Comment: @Akina, такой вопрос нужно вынести на MSE и запросить у разработчиков замену удаления вопроса/ответа на диссоциацию.

Comment: @Akina , у меня уже два вопроса на MSE готовятся..если хотите могу и этот вопрос вынести

Comment: Если Вы разделяете мою позицию по данному вопросу - конечно, выносите. Если вопросы, особенно качественные и/или отвеченные, перестанут пропадать по велению левой пятки автора, станет только лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вносящим правки в заголовок вопроса копипастить оригинальный заголовок в тело вопроса.

Может даже какую-нибудь плашку сделать под это дело, например:

```
Оригинальный заголовок:
***Прастити тупова, нипанимаю фчем ашипка.***
```

---

Comment: а зачем такое? все кто интересуются правками, могут в историю правок глянуть

Comment: а затем, что в истории правок без политры не разобраться. я как-то полез, ну его нафиг. 
к тому же гораздо нагляднее и новичку сразу станет понятно, почему именно так, а не иначе. 

п.с. ладно. пусть без плашки. Минус-то за что? =)

Comment: Хз, не мой минус)